# How can I fixate a number of rows, as a sort of header, in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have this fixed-size ASCII file, but created some headers above it in the first 10 rows of the file. The file itself is 200+rows, so if I scroll down, I can't see my headers. How can I fixate the view in Notepad++, so I can see row 1-10 always and can scroll down to rows 200+?
(Like you can do in Microsoft Excel - Freeze panes)
Or is this impossible in Notepad++

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you want, but you can do:

- clone the file to other view
- right click on separation line, then choose "rotate to the (right or left)"
- position the horizontal separator where you want (just under the line #10)

The two view are independent when scrolling, so, you can scroll the second view and keep the 10 first lines visible in the first view.

Comment: It's not the solution I was looking for, now there's space between the header and the data, but it works for now.
Thanks!